# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable- MULTIPROCESSING using POOL

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing

I am tryng to read a csv file and find the average of columns. Can't crack the pool multiprocessing part!
Keeps giving an error for the multiprocessing section. Serial processing is working!

```
import os
from multiprocessing import Pool
import pandas as pd
import time
import statistics
    def average(listed_marks):
        avg=[]
        i=[]
        for i in listed_marks:
            avg.append(statistics.mean(i))

        return avg



    if __name__ == '__main__':

        list_of_marks=[]  

        df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Radhika\Desktop\RADZ Projects\Xoriant\data.csv")
        n = df['STUDENT ID'].count() #no of rows

        for i in range(n):  #to obtain the list of lists
            a=list(df.iloc[i , 3:6])
            a = list(map(int, a)) #converting the lists into int to perform mean
            list_of_marks.append(list(a))

    # ---------------------MP---------------------------------------------------

        s1= time.time()    

        p = Pool()
        avg_mp = p.map(average, list_of_marks) #passed the average function and iterator is a list of list
        df['Average'] = avg_mp
        p.close()
        p.join()

        print(f"Processing took {time.time() - s1} using Multi-Processing")
```

Comment: the csv file is just marks of students in 3 subjects.

Comment: What line is giving the error?

Comment: line 12, in average
    avg.append(statistics.mean(i))

Comment: statistics.mean() takes a list or iterable.

Comment: @quamrana Can you explain what the map function does with the arguments passed to it? Doesn't it just feed the argument to the function passed in the map?

Comment: It treats the argument as an iterable and feeds each item to a call to the function and gathers the returns into a list. It’s just like the normal map which you have already used, just with multiprocessing.

Comment: @qamrana MP doess't seem to reduce processing time

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your average() function should just be:

```
def average(listed_marks):
   return statistics.mean(listed_marks)
```

Comment: Basically, I have a csv file with students ID, first name, last name, maths, Science, English....

Comment: I want to add a new column to calculate the average. 
So I did was formed a list of lists containg the marks, then calculating a list of averages of the list.. and then appending that list as a new column to the csv file.. I want to you pool to expidite the process for large data

Comment: THANK YOU! @quamrana

Comment: Worked with that!

Comment: @quaram the multiprocessing doesn't help reducing the time...